# How to merge table in snowflake using snowpark scala

Tags: scala, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table named SOME_SNOWFLAKE_TABLE in snowflake

I want to Merge SOME_SNOWFLAKE_TABLE with another table SOME_TARGET_TABLE in snowflake.

Below is the approach provided in snowflake documentation. But this is not working for me.

```html
target.merge(source, target("id") === source("id"))
  .whenMatched.update(Map("description" -> source("description")))
  .collect()
```

My approach is below, but it failed.

```html
val source = session.table("SOME_SNOWFLAKE_TABLE")
val target_table = "SOME_TARGET_TABLE"

target_table.merge(source, target_table("id") === source("id"))
  .whenMatched.update(Map("description" -> source("description")))
  .collect()
```

I tried another approach as shown below, it also failed.

```html
val source = session.table("SOME_SNOWFLAKE_TABLE")
val target_table = session.table("SOME_TARGET_TABLE")

target_table.merge(source, target_table("id") === source("id"))
  .whenMatched.update(Map("description" -> source("description")))
  .collect()
```

Could someone help me here?

Comment: What is not working? What are the error messages? Is the data loading but not in the way you expect - if so, what is being loaded and what result are you expecting?

Comment: The error is cannot resolve symbol merge. I am not able to even run the job